# get the bytes of a file to an array

Tags: basic, freebasic

I use the following 9 lines to put the bytes of a file `NameF` in vector `T()` in FreeBasic 0.4.6 FBide.

Is there a better or shorter way?

```vb
DIM L as ulong, NameF as string
Input "Enter Name of the File", NameF
Open NameF For Binary As #1
L= LOF(1)
Close #1
DIM T(1 to L) As Ubyte
Open NameF For Binary Access Read As #1
Get #1, , T()
Close #1
```

The 9 lines work OK. I am looking for improvement if feasible.

Comment: why do you close and reopen? I don't know your specific  Basic, but LOF shouldn't change the position in the file (you should be able to issue GET immediately after the LOF

Comment: Why do you close and reopen the file? It's not necessary. Remove the first `Close #1` and the second `Open`. As an FYI: Please make an effort to properly format code when posting here, so that it's more readable. For help doing so, click the`?` button to the left side of the toolbar when posting or editing.

Comment: in case it's working then it may be a better candidate for [codereview.se]

Comment: 2 lines off is an improvement, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

> 2 lines off is an improvement, thanks to everyone

Then 3 lines off is better (no need for the separate *L* variable, as well as the redundant `Close` and `Open` commands):

```
DIM NameF as string
Input "Enter Name of the File", NameF
Open NameF For Binary Access Read As #1
DIM T(1 to LOF(1)) As Ubyte
Get #1, , T()
Close #1
```